# PHP query runner on YAML

Tags: php, xpath, yaml

Is there any library available in PHP which can run query in YAML file? Like what xpath does for XML file.

Example:

```
uuid: a04c4da2-39c0-42c4-9a26-5e4e35473ff2
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - page_manager.page.group_s_homepage
```

and then using Xpath like a query we can find the parent of config. The reason is I have a YAML which is around 25k line long and I want to do some migration on that.

Comment: There is no specified equivalent to XPath for YAML, mainly because YAML is meant to be loaded into native object rather than a DOM.

Comment: Ok, so the best way in my case I guess is to convert YAML to XML and then run XPATH on it.

Comment: If you have a YAML-to-XML conversion tool that is able to process your input, that would probably be the path of lowest effort.

Comment: I implemented that for FluentDOM using the Symfony/YAML library: https://github.com/ThomasWeinert/FluentDOM-YAML-Symfony

Comment: So I completed this task on the previous week, and in my case, my YAML to XML tool was not that great and can not convert 25 k lines properly, I converted the YAML to an array then used multiple loops to find the relation. I yet need to test solution from "ThW", but it looks promising to me.